# Making violin plots for a time series in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I'm trying to make violin plots for my study with repeated measures. Temperature was measured every minute during rest, exercise, and recovery. I want to visualize my data using violin plots every 10 minutes. Connecting the time points with a trace line.

```r
dat <- structure(list(Rectal = c(37.7471747885623, 37.7456113500327, 37.7424555990783, 37.7387318056167, 37.7346179421912, 37.7299800892173, 37.7230333767273, 37.7170454766354, 37.7097134366366, 37.7031506231242, 37.6977658019971, 37.6640745122859, 37.6699817796991, 37.6796325244397, 37.6906170952057, 37.7023743423906, 37.7146427686485, 37.7313029547686, 37.7502699566081, 37.7701378827216), Time = structure(1:20, .Label = c("00:00:00", "00:01:00", "00:02:00", "00:03:00", "00:04:00", "00:05:00", "00:06:00", "00:07:00", "00:08:00", "00:09:00", "00:10:00", "00:11:00", "00:12:00", "00:13:00", "00:14:00", "00:15:00", "00:16:00", "00:17:00", "00:18:00", "00:19:00", "00:20:00", "00:21:00", "00:22:00", "00:23:00", "00:24:00", "00:25:00", "00:26:00", "00:27:00", "00:28:00", "00:29:00", "00:30:00", "00:31:00", "00:32:00", "00:33:00", "00:34:00", "00:35:00", "00:36:00", "00:37:00", "00:38:00", "00:39:00", "00:40:00", "00:41:00", "00:42:00", "00:43:00", "00:44:00", "00:45:00", "00:46:00", "00:47:00", "00:48:00", "00:49:00", "00:50:00", "00:51:00", "00:52:00", "00:53:00", "00:54:00", "00:55:00", "00:56:00", "00:57:00", "00:58:00", "00:59:00", "01:00:00", "01:01:00", "01:02:00", "01:03:00", "01:04:00", "01:05:00", "01:06:00", "01:07:00", "01:08:00", "01:09:00", "01:10:00", "01:11:00", "01:12:00", "01:13:00", "01:14:00", "01:15:00", "01:16:00", "01:17:00", "01:18:00", "01:19:00", "01:20:00", "01:21:00", "01:22:00", "01:23:00", "01:24:00", "01:25:00", "01:26:00", "01:27:00", "01:28:00", "01:29:00"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image: This is an example of how I want the plot to look like]

Who knows how to do this? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello VerneNL check this website https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/violin.html

Comment: you can use geom_segment() see: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_segment.html